# Question index not updating when I click next button

Tags: javascript

I have written this code its just that when I click the next button the questions and answers don't update and go to the next question in the array, but it shows the first question and answers when the page loads. I'm not sure what I havent done here.

```js
const questiontext= document.getElementById('question-text');
const A= document.getElementById('OptionA');
const B= document.getElementById('OptionB');
const C= document.getElementById('OptionC');
const D= document.getElementById('OptionD');
const options= document.getElementsByClassName('options');
const nextbutton= document.getElementById('next');
const submitbutton= document.getElementById('submit');
const questions=[
    {
        question: "What is the best item at mcdonalds?",
        answerA: "Fries",
        answerB: "Big Mac",
        answerC: "Mcnuggets",
        answerD: "Quarter Pounder",
        correctanswer: "Big Mac"
    },
    {
        question: "What is the cheapest thing on the mcdonalds menu?",
        answerA: "Fries",
        answerB: "Double Cheeseburger",
        answerC: "Happy Meal",
        answerD: "Orange juice",
        correctanswer: "Fries"
    },
    {
        question: "What is the least popular item at mcdonalds?",
        answerA: "Filet O Fish",
        answerB: "Hamburger",
        answerC: "Veggie Deluxe",
        answerD: "Mineral water",
        correctanswer: "Filet O Fish"
    },
    {
        question: "How many dips are you allowed with 20 Mcnuggets?",
        answerA: "2",
        answerB: "4",
        answerC: "3",
        answerD: "6",
        correctanswer: "4"
    }
];
//Question index at start
const questionindex= 0;
const currentquestion= () =>{
    questiontext.innerHTML= questions[questionindex].question;
    A.innerHTML= questions[questionindex].answerA;
    B.innerHTML= questions[questionindex].answerB;
    C.innerHTML= questions[questionindex].answerC;
    D.innerHTML= questions[questionindex].answerD;
    if(questionindex === questions.length){
       submitbutton.classList.remove('hidden'); 
    }
}

const nextquestion= () =>{
    questionindex++
}
//Load first question and answers
currentquestion(questionindex);
//Button to display next question
nextbutton.addEventListener('click', nextquestion);
```

Comment: Call `currentquestion` in `nextquestion` to update the display.

Comment: ok will try that

Comment: Yes, and as others pointed out, change `questionindex` to `let`, so that it can change. Using `const` everywhere else is fine.

Comment: Thanks alot this really helped, needed to show only one question at a time instead of a list of questions  for my course project.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
const questionindex
```

to

```
let questionindex
```

Answer (score 0):

change the **const** and replace it with a **let** or **var**